# Zenshop Wordpress theme CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a problem editing css of zenshop theme. On homepage there is a product display in grid of 4X2 but since i have 6 major categories of products i want to make it 3X2 but i am not able to do that plz help. my site http://ruchitraders.com

I am trying to modify the following code

```
#shelf {
width: 980px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding:0px 10px;
}

.box {
width: 220px;
position:relative;
background: #fff;
margin: 30px 0px 30px 20px;
float: left;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px #ddd;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px #ddd;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px #ddd; 

}

.lastbox{
float:right;
margin-right:20px;
}


.productshot{
width:170px;
height:200px;
margin:10px 25px 10px 25px;
}

.boxtitle {

}

.boxtitle h2 {
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0px 10px;
padding: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 120%;
border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}

.boxtitle h2 a:link,.boxtitle h2 a:visited {
color: #666;

}
```

Plz help I am new to php.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to add a question mark to make it easy for the viewers to answer you..

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width of .box to something like 300px and adjust the margins accordingly.

You have a class of .lastbox which will move to the third box and the sixth one.

Also remove the clear div that you have sitting in the middle of the LI elements as a DIV can't be a child of a UL.

If you need to clear your floats add "overflow: hidden" to #home-content